How to prove the following matrix norm inequality
I want to proof this inequality:$\left\|\hat{\mathbf{\Sigma}}_s^{-1}-\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\right\|_F \leq\left\|\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\right\|_F \frac{\left\|\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\left(\hat{\mathbf{\Sigma}}_s-\mathbf{\Sigma}\right)\right\|_F}{1-\left\|\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\left(\hat{\mathbf{\Sigma}}_s-\mathbf{\Sigma}\right)\right\|_F}$,whenever $\left\|\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\right\|_F \cdot\left\|\hat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}_s-\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right\|_F<1$.
I have tried Lemma Von Neumann in matrix inversion, but it failed.

What are the matrices? Dimensions? Diagonals? Symmetric?

If $A$ is a real square matrix recall that the Frobenius norm is  defined by $\|A\|^2=\|A\|_F^2=trace{AA^T}$ and that
$$\|AB\|\leq \|A\|\|B\|\ \ (1)$$
The proof of (1) goes as follows. We write $BB^T=UDU^T$ where $U$ is orthogonal and $D$ is diagonal with non negative coefficients $d_1,\ldots,d_n$ and we write $S= U^TAA^TU=(s_{ij}) $ (which is semi positive definite). Now:
$$\|AB\|^2=trace(ABB^TA^T)=trace(BB^TA^TA)=trace(UDU^T A^TA)$$$$=trace (DS)=\sum_id_is_{ii}\leq( \sum _id_i)(\sum_i s_{ii})$$$$=(trace(U^TBB^TU))trace (U^TAA^TU)=\|B\|^2\|A\|^2$$ This proves (1)  (a classical fact).
Coming back to the problem, denote for simplicity $A=\hat{\Sigma}^{-1}_s$, $B=\Sigma^{-1}$ and $C=B-A$. We have to show
$$\|C\|\leq \|B\|\frac{\|B(B^{-1}-A^{-1})\|}{1-\|B(B^{-1}-A^{-1})\|}=\|B\|\frac{\|CA^{-1})\|}{1-\|CA^{-1})\|}\ \ (2)$$
under the hypothesis $\|B\|\|B^{-1}CA^{-1}\|<1.$ This hypothesis implies that $$\|CA^{-1}\|=\|BB^{-1}CA^{-1}\|\stackrel{(1)}{\leq} \|B\|\|B^{-1}CA^{-1}\|<1.$$ Therefore (2) is equivalent to
$$\|C\|\leq (\|B\|+\|C\|)\|CA^{-1}\| \ \ (3)$$ To conclude
$$\|C\|=\|CA^{-1}A\|\stackrel{(1)}{\leq }\|CA^{-1}\|\|B+C\|\leq (\|B\|+\|C\|)\|CA^{-1}\|,$$ which is (3).
